# How do I create a json inside another json?

Tags: c#, json

I need to create a json inside another json, I'm creating the json like this:

```
Turnover turnover = new Turnover();
                    turnover.DealerUserName = username;
                    turnover.CardNumber = cardnumber;
                    turnover.InvoiceNumber = invoicenumber;
                    turnover.Amount = total;
                    turnover.Currency = currency;
                    turnover.InvoiceDate = tempo;
                    turnover.SegmentNumber = segment;
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnover);
```

This is how I create the `Turnover` class:

```
public class Turnover
    {
        public string DealerUserName { get; set; }
        public long CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public short SegmentNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

But I need to create a variable in Turnover with the features that are in the following class:

```
  public class product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductGroup { get; set; }
        public long Code { get; set; }
        public decimal Amout { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Referece { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I do that ? I was trying to do it with a `list` like this :

```
public class Turnover
    {
public List<product> TurnoverDetails { get; set; } 
    }
Turnover turnover = new Turnover();
turnover.TurnoverDetails.Add(new product() { ProductName = "", ProductGroup = "", Amout = 0, Code = 0, Quantity = 0, Referece = "", });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnover);
```

I liked json to be like this:

[image]

Comment: And the expected JSON should look like what?

Comment: @Vanna I just guess he gets a NullReferenceException with his code ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo i will edit my question with that sorry

Comment: And please add the real problem. Did you get an exception?

Comment: JSON is a plain text format and you should post the JSON as text and not as an image hosted somewhere

Comment: BTW the JSON from screenshot is **invalid**

Comment: @SirRufo yes I got the NullRefereceException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding it to TurnoverDetails list, you must create an object. please find the sample code below,

```
public class Turnover
{
   public Turnover()
   {
       TurnoverDetails = new List<product>();
   }
   public List<product> TurnoverDetails { get; set; } 
}
Turnover turnover = new Turnover();
turnover.TurnoverDetails.Add(new product() { ProductName = "", ProductGroup 
= "", Amout = 0, Code = 0, Quantity = 0, Referece = "", });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnover);
```

Comment: Or `public List<product> TurnoverDetails { get; set; } = new List<product>();` and no need for constructor

Answer (score 0):

Add property of type list

```
public class Turnover
        {
            public string DealerUserName { get; set; }
            public long CardNumber { get; set; }
            public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public string Currency { get; set; }
            public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
            public short SegmentNumber { get; set; }
            public List<product> Products = new List<product>();
        }
```

and then add product in turnover object

```
 Turnover turnover = new Turnover();
    turnover.Products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "", ProductGroup = "", Amout = 0, Code = 0, Quantity = 0, Referece = "", });
turnover.Products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "", ProductGroup = "", Amout = 0, Code = 0, Quantity = 0, Referece = "", });
turnover.Products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "", ProductGroup = "", Amout = 0, Code = 0, Quantity = 0, Referece = "", });


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnover);
```